Continuity equation for a perturbed system
I'm reading J. Frank's book, "Accretion Power in Astrophysics", and on chapter 2, section 2.4, he studies the perturbation of a system initially in equilibrium. The perturbation is given by,
$$
P \rightarrow P_{0} + P^{'}, \hspace{0.5cm} \rho \rightarrow \rho_{0} + \rho^{'}, \hspace{0.5cm} \boldsymbol{v} \rightarrow \boldsymbol{v}^{'},
$$
where $P$, $\rho$ and $v$ are the perturbed pressure, volumetric density and velocity, respectively. The analogous symbols with $_{0}$ subscript are the initial values for these quantities (where $v_{0} = 0$), and $'$ stands for the perturbed variables.
With this perturbation, he obtains the following expression for the continuity equation,
$$
\frac{\partial \rho^{'}}{\partial t} + \rho_{0}\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot \boldsymbol{v^{'}} = 0.
$$
The problem is I can't get this expression. I tried the following: starting with the continuity equation,
$$
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot (\rho \boldsymbol{v}) = 0,
$$
and opening the divergence operator, writing the quantities explicitly showing its initial and perturbed terms, we have,
$$
\frac{\partial (\rho_{0} + \rho^{'})}{\partial t} + \boldsymbol{v}^{'} \cdot \boldsymbol{\nabla} (\rho_{0} + \rho^{'}) + (\rho_{0} + \rho^{'}) \boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot \boldsymbol{v^{'}} = 0.
$$
I know the term $\partial \rho_{0}/\partial t = 0$, because the system was in equilibrium, and we can rearrange the last two terms as,
$$
\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot (\rho_{0}\boldsymbol{v^{'}}) + \boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot (\rho^{'}\boldsymbol{v^{'}}),
$$
but I don't know how these terms can turn out to be $\rho_{0}\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot \boldsymbol{v^{'}}$.
Update for people who have the same doubt
In this case, we are applying perturbation theory to variables which corresponds to a system which is initially in equilibrium, that is, we are varying slightly its values. So, if the ' quantities are small, the multiplication of two of these quantities is even smaller, and, in a first approximation, can be neglected. So the term,
$$
\boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot (\rho^{'}\boldsymbol{v^{'}}) \approx 0,
$$
and then, we get, as a final result for the continuity equation, the expression,
$$
\frac{\partial \rho^{'}}{\partial t} + \rho_{0}\boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot \boldsymbol{v}^{'} = 0.
$$

You seem to have done everything right, so it's difficult to see what the problem is. However, if you're asking why
$$ \boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot (\rho_o \textbf{v}')$$
can be written as
$$\rho_0 \boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot \textbf{v}',$$
it's simply because the $\rho_0$ is a constant, and can be taken in front of the derivative.

I was just having a dificulty in realizing that v' \cdot \rho' can be neglected, as I mentioned in the update I did on the question. Anyway, thank you!

Yes, that's right. That term is so small it can be neglected.
